# App makes the apps screen slow

Tags: android, performance, background, android-background

I am making a basic app in which the users can check their "dinning balance", i managed to do this by parsing the proper web page.

My app works just fine, but i found that when i exit it, the Current Running Apps Screen (Android app manager) goes really slow, even laggy, when my app is being displayed.

I tried to kill my app using the following methods so the app won't be running in background when i exit it, but it didnt work:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    System.exit(0);        
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();      
    System.exit(0);
}`
```

So right now, i am trying to figure out why does the "Current Apps" screen is going slower due to my app. My app is not executing anything in the background, its just idle. Newbie here.

Comment: What are you doing in your onPause()?

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me a few days ago and I figured I messed up with my res folders and a very large icon ended up in my res/drawable folder.

Make sure your app's icon isn't too large (recommended specifications for icons can be found here: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html). Check *all* drawable folders (xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi...) inside `[Your app folder]/app/src/main/res/drawable/`

Hope I could help.
Happy coding :)

Comment: This was exactly the problem, i had an image that had too much resolution. Thank you!